# Importing Variables from other functions

Tags: python, function, variables

I've tried searching and trying suggestions people made for others but its not working for me, here is my code:

```
def CreateAccount():
    FirstName = input('What is your first name?: ')
    SecondName = input('What is your second name?: ')
    Age = input('How old are you?: ')
    AreaLive = input("What area do you live in?: ")
    return FirstName, SecondName, Age, AreaLive

def DisplayAccountInfo(FirstName,SecondName,Age,AreaLive):
    print("Your Firstname is",FirstName)
    print("Your Secondname is",SecondName)
    print("You are",Age," years old")
    print("You live in the",AreaLive," area")
    return




def ConfirmAccountF():
    ConfirmAccount = input("Do you have an account? y,n; ")
    if  ConfirmAccount == "n":
        CreateAccount()

    else: #ConfirmAccount -- 'y'
        DisplayAccountInfo()

while True:

    ConfirmAccountF()
```

So its just supposed to run indefinitely for now, but what I want it to do is pass the variables from 'CreateAccount' into 'DisplayAccountInfo'.

When I press anything other than *n* for 'ConfirmAccount' I get that the variables are undefined.

If I set it manually in 'DisplayAccountInfo()' then it doesn't throw any errors.

This is just me messing about and trying to understand python, if anyone can help that would be great.

Comment: the `createAccount` is returning the variables but you are not assigning them to anything. Do something like `data = CreateAccount()` instead and then pass the `*data` in the `DisplayAccountInfo()` function

Comment: What account-information do you want to show in `DisplayAccountInfo()`? If the user types `y`, how do you know which account to display info for?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [unpacking operator, *](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists):

`DisplayAccountInfo(*CreateAccount())`

What this does is takes the tuple of four strings returned by `CreateAccount` and converts them into four arguments to be passed as separate parameters to `DisplayAccountInfo`. Whereas if you omitted the `*` operator and just called `DisplayAccountInfo(CreateAccount())`, that would pass a single tuple argument to `DisplayAccountInfo`, resulting in a `TypeError` exception (because `DisplayAccountInfo` expects four arguments, not one).

Of course if you also need to save the strings returned from `CreateAccount` for later use, you'll need to do that in between calling `CreateAccount` and `DisplayAccountInfo`.

Answer (score 0):

The variable you declared on `CreateAccount()` can't be accesed by its name from the outside. To pass the information to another function you need to store its values first:

```
first_name, second_name, age, area = "", "", "", ""

def ConfirmAccountF():
    ConfirmAccount = input("Do you have an account? y,n; ")
    if  ConfirmAccount == "n":
        first_name, second_name, age, area = CreateAccount()

    else: #ConfirmAccount -- 'y'
        DisplayAccountInfo(first_name, second_name, age, area)
```

Comment: Also, my code is not the best, but I think is the easy to understand without further knowledge of python